# When I am using the provider package in Flutter to load data from an API into a list it repeatedly calls the API, how do I fix it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, flutter-state

I am trying to lode data from an api call that retrieves a map, I am able to get the map from the api to display how I want it to, however it repeatedly calls the api meaning the list keeps on refreshing. Even though I have tried setting the listener to false, it works but I have to manually refresh the app for it to work?

Additional Info: Assigning and Retrieving Data

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Stores with ChangeNotifier {

  var s_length;

  Future<List<Store>> getStores(String storeCatName) async {
    final queryParameters = {
      "store_category_name": storeCatName,
    };
    try {
      //TODO this is the issue - must fix.
      final uri = Uri.http("url", 'url', queryParameters);
      //print(uri);
      final response = await http.get(uri);
      //print(response.statusCode);
      //print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<Store> stores = storeFromJson(response.body);
        _stores = stores;
        //print(_stores);
        print("lenght: ${_stores.length}");
        Store store;
        for(store in _stores) {
          store.products = Products().products(store.storeId);
        }
        //check if this is correct
        notifyListeners();
        //return stores;

      } else {
        print("error1");
        return List<Store>();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return List<Store>();
    }
    //notifyListeners();
    print(_stores);
  }

  List<Store> get favoriteItems {
    //return _stores.where((storeItem) => storeItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  bool isNotFull(){
    if (_stores.isEmpty){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  int get numberOfStores{
    return s_length;
  }

  List<Store> _stores = [];

  List<Store> stores (String storeCatName){

    getStores(storeCatName);
    //print("cpp; + $s_length");
    //notifyListeners();
    return _stores;
  }

}
```

```
 final storesProvider = Provider.of<Stores>(
      context, listen: false
    );

    storesProvider.getStores(categoryName);

    final providerStoreList = storesProvider.stores(category.storeCategoryName);
```

Additional Info: Builder for List:

```
child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: providerStoreList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                  value: providerStoreList[index],
                  child: StoreItem(),
                )));
```

If any additional information is required just let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code where you are retrieving the data and where are assigning it...

Comment: @AdarshSrivastava hope the latest edit helps

Answer (score 0):

Use

> listen: false;

```
   var ourClient = Provider.of<CartBlock>(context, listen: false);
```

Comment: When I set listen to false, it doesn't load the data the first time . Instead I have to refresh the app using ctrl + s and then it will display as intended.

Comment: for this u need to call the provider in your init() method then 1st time it wont be a problem for you and then it will work , do listen false.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the listener to false means that your widget won't build again when notifyListeners() is called.

So, that might not be the issue.

The only reason I can think of is calling the API again from the build method,
which might happen if you are using a ListView builder.
So, every time you might be scrolling the ListView your API would call again.

Comment: It is being called later in a ListView builder, so how would I then rectify this?

Comment: You should not use your stores() function in the ListView rather use a variable , so you get the already stored value, and not call the function which in turn calls your API.

Also, adding your build method snippet would help.

Comment: @AdarshManoj I completely agree with HasipTimurtas...you should not call the getstores method in builder, calling it at the time of initState would help...